# Javascript hide table cell on button click

Tags: javascript, css

I try to hide one cell of table using javascript. I want to send only id of the whole table to the function and than get to that cell using `childNodes` property.
Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hiden{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function change(){
            t = document.getElementById('table');
            row = t.node.childNodes[0];
            row.node.childNodes[0].className='hidden'; 
        } 
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='change()'>Change</button>
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Hi</td>
            <td>See you</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I try to hide "Hi".

I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined`
on this line:
`row = t.node.childNodes[0];`

The larger goal is to show only 4 columns of longer table and showing hidden using next/previous buttons. If you know some library to do this please let me know. 
Thank you for help.

Comment: What is that `node` property you keep using (e.g. in `t.node.childNodes[0]`)?

Comment: `node` is not a property of the element assigned to variable `t`. [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns the `<table>` element and `node` is not a property of that element

Comment: `<tbody>` will get added to the DOM if you don't have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, node is not available in the Node you got using `document.getElementById('table')`;

[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/huvop/1/edit)

Please make the necessary changes in the change()

```
     function change() {
        var t = document.getElementById('table');
        var row = t.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        row.className='hidden'; 
    }
```

For pagination, You could use jQuery's :lt() and :gt() for implementation

In the CSS, you have a typo. The class name should be `.hidden`

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the cell wrong

change your js to the following:

```
function change() {
    t = document.getElementById('table');
    row = t.rows[0];
    row.cells[0].className='hidden'; 
}
```

And it should work: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6agDZ/)

Also, please note you have spelt your `hidden` class wrong (missed a d)

Answer (score 1):

You can use just one line:

```
function change() {
   document.getElementById('table').rows[0].cells[0].className='hidden';         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code,

```
<style type="text/css">
.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
<script>
function newchange()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    for (var i = 0, cell; cell = table.cells[i]; i++) {
         //iterate through cells
         //cells would be accessed using the "cell" variable assigned in the for loop
        if(i == 0 || cell.id == 'firstCell'){
        cell.className='hidden';
        }
    }
}
 </script>
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <button onclick='newchange()'>Change</button>
 <table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td id="firstCell">Hi</td>
    <td>See you</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
```

Loop through all cells and then control which cell to hide or show by using loop variable counter ('i' in this case) or by cell id.